# AbsoVal.java:11: error: class DoubAbso is public, should be declared in a file named DoubAbso.java public class DoubAbso {

Tags: java

[image]

This is my code and after compiling it, I received the error in the title. Any help?

I tried switching AbsoVal with DoubAbso and vice versa but nothing worked.

Comment: Every public class that's not inside another class has to be in its own file.  The name of that file has to match the name of the class.  In your case, that means you have to split your program across two files.

Comment: How do I put another class in its own file?

Comment: "How do I put another class in its own file?" Well - the code that you showed is in a file, called `AbsoVal.java`, correct? You put the `public class AbsoVal` into that class, correct? *How did you do that? Now, do the same thing* with a new file, named `DoubAbso`, to put the `public class DoubAbso` there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)